# Regarding using GPU with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I installed tensorflow-gpu following (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) But when I import tensorflow I got this message. When I went through stackoverflow's previous posts, it seems like the message is not an issue.

[image]

But after that when I tired to execute a code, I met with this error. Can someone help me to figure this out. I'm using ubuntu 22.04 LTS

[image]

I tried going through blog posts but non of them worked out. I'm expecting to solve this error.

Comment: Please include code, errors, et cetera as text, and not as images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please confirm if you have followed all the steps mentioned under the GPU setup section in the same link along with installed Python and Tensorflow version details.

Comment: Hi @Chamith Dilshan, This is known issue in Ubuntu 22.04. Please refer to the step 6 in the step by step instructions section in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to fix the error. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.